# Change option in Google places autocomplete

Tags: google-maps

I am working with Google Maps API V3. The following is my code to set-up for autocomplete:

```
var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: elmts.rs_country.val()}
 };
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start_address, options);
```

This works just fine. However, I need to dynamically change the country restriction.

How can I change the 'componentRestrictions' to another country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this [Google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions). You can use the method `setComponentRestrictions`

Comment: Direct link to that method: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#Autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions